# Need to write into a file after some characters in shell

Tags: shell, echo

I am trying to echo in an IP into a file and it should be placed right after the variable name.

ie: at the moment my file content is IP_addr=

After echo it should be IP_addr=10.35.42.110

Anyone with a solution?

thanks

Comment: How does your file look like? Is `IP_addr` the only text on that line?

Comment: `sed 's/IP_addr=$/&10.35.42.100/' filename`

Comment: Hey thanks! That works but i suppose the same action cannot be performed using 'echo'?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should solve your problem

```
echo "this will append to an existing file" >> filename
```

Answer (score 0):

> `sed 's/IP_addr=$/&10.35.42.100/' filename` –  devnull
>
> Hey thanks! That works but i suppose the same action cannot be performed using 'echo'?

If you insist:

```
sed s/IP_addr=\$/\&`echo 10.35.42.100`/ filename
```